# Function for setting default values of controls in web browser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I wanted to define a public function by which I can set default values of some controls in a web browser control.
The web browser shows an HTML file.
Here is what I have come up with so far;however,the "NullReferenceException was unhandled" occurs:

```
public void SetDefaultValue(string ControlID,string Value)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(ControlID).InnerText = Value;
}
```

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled means yo do n't have a htmlelemet with this id,or your webpage navigation is not completed.could you add more code about what you write

Comment: you may need to wait till the document is ready or fully loaded..

Comment: @irsog : I do have an htmlelement with this ID because I copied the ID from my html file
Here is how I call it in my form load:
htmlLoadWebbrowser1.SetDefaultValue("Name", "comments");
Is it wrong?

Comment: can you add you html code?

Comment: Sure:
Name:<textarea id="Name" name="comments" cols="16" rows="1"></textarea>

Comment: @Amitd:You are right,thank you it was fixed,I do not know how to mark your comment as an answer

Comment: @Pedram np  .. i posted the answer for you . pls mark it answer :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the document to get loaded properly

```
public void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
   var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
   webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Name").InnerText = "Hello World";

}    

private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var wbrowser = new WebBrowser(); // or can be existing object
      // Add web broswer to form or panel here.. 
     wbrowser.DocumentCompleted +=new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
     wbrowser.Navigate("your_page_url_here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I write an Example For You:
Fist `Navigate` to your address or set its `DocumentText`.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><textarea id=\"Name\" name=\"comments\" cols=\"16\" rows=\"1\">Some Things</textarea></body></html>";
        }
```

when your page loaded you can get its element.

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
         webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Name").InnerText="Some Thing";
        }
```

Comment: :Thank you my friend,but Admitd's code work more effectively.
I am making a user control and I cannot set the html value code myself.
Thank you again my friend :)

Comment: :Thank you for answering my questions,your answers have been so helpful for me.